# Wrong output on solar inverter

Tags: solar-cell, inverter, proteus

I have started working on proteus two days ago for my college project and I’m having some problem in the solar inverter.

Diagram which I refered for making this inverter:
[image]

[image]

And I tried to recreate this in proteus 8

[image]

[image]

where I’m getting -3.34v instead of 9V

I want suggestions on how can I fix this problem.

Comment: The first reason could be because you aren't measuring the actual output.  You are measuring two individual outputs that only switch to ground.

Comment: Oh my, this is a crude half-bridge driver circuit. C12 shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 1):

You have no load or positive supply connected to a MOSFETs. If the transistors are off then they are open-circuit.

The voltmeter probably has infinite input impedance and you're picking up stray voltage through the MOSFET gates capacitance.

Try adding in your output transformer or temporarily adding a pull-down resistor on each of the meter points.